# CMake: build subproject depending on other's subproject header

Tags: c++, cmake, include

I have a project containing two subdirectories (simplified):

```
project(superproj)    
add_subdirectory(foo-api)
add_subdirectory(bar-api)
```

`bar-api` uses `foo-api` headers and expects them to be installed in `$PREFIX/include/foo` (its files contain `#include <foo/header.h>`)

But when I compile this superproject, I don't want `foo-api` actually installed in my system. How do I build `bar-api` in this case? Is it possible to do so without messing with `bar-api`'s CMakeFile? I want to keep these two projects as much independent as possible, so one could just clone and build them separately.

Comment: What about [`target_include_directories(... PUBLIC ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) for `foo-api`? That's normally the way to make your library self-propagating it's include directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html):

```
project(superproj) 
include_directories(foo-api/path/to/includes)   
add_subdirectory(foo-api)
add_subdirectory(bar-api)
```

It's action is propagated to all subdirectories in current directory. And yes, consider `target_include_directories` for modern versions of CMake, as Florian mentioned in comments.

Comment: I think `include_directories` isn't going to work, because the path to headers in the project folder and the path where they get installed differ. I mean, they locate in `foo-api/include/some_header.h`, but install to `/usr/include/foo/some_header.h`. And in `bar-api` files it's `#include <foo/some_header.h>`. So I can't just add `include_directories` without changing that `#include` directive in `bar-api` files.

Comment: @c_spk That's an important concern. Looks like you need to make an alias for include path, but compilers lack this feature, so build system has nothing to do here. As a workaround, you can create `foo-api/foo` symlink which points to `foo-api/include` and add `foo-api` to include_directories. Again, cmake lacks symlink creation feature (maybe because not all filesystems support them?), and you'll need to automate symlinking for all supported platforms using `add_custom_target` or `add_custom_command`.